# Rspec: expect vs expect with block - what's the difference?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec2

Just learning rspec syntax and I noticed that this code works:

```
  context "given a bad list of players" do
    let(:bad_players) { {} }

    it "fails to create given a bad player list" do
       expect{ Team.new("Random", bad_players) }.to raise_error
     end 
  end
```

But this code doesn't:

```
  context "given a bad list of players" do
    let(:bad_players) { {} }

    it "fails to create given a bad player list" do
       expect( Team.new("Random", bad_players) ).to raise_error
     end 
  end
```

It gives me this error:

```
Team given a bad list of players fails to create given a bad player list
     Failure/Error: expect( Team.new("Random", bad_players) ).to raise_error
     Exception:
       Exception
     # ./lib/team.rb:6:in `initialize'
     # ./spec/team_spec.rb:23:in `new'
     # ./spec/team_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

My question is:

1. Why does this happen?
2. What is the difference between the former and later example exactly in ruby?

I am also looking for **rules** on when to use one over the other

One more example of the same but inverse results, where this code works:

```
  it "has a list of players" do
    expect(Team.new("Random").players).to be_kind_of Array
  end
```

But this code fails

```
  it "has a list of players" do
    expect{ Team.new("Random").players }.to be_kind_of Array
  end
```

Error I get in this case is:

```
Failure/Error: expect{ Team.new("Random").players }.to be_kind_of Array
       expected #<Proc:0x007fbbbab29580@/Users/amiterandole/Documents/current/ruby_sandbox/tdd-ruby/spec/team_spec.rb:9> to be a kind of Array
     # ./spec/team_spec.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The class I am testing looks like this:

```
class Team
  attr_reader :name, :players

  def initialize(name, players = [])
    raise Exception unless players.is_a? Array

    @name = name
    @players = players
  end
end
```

Answer (score 78, accepted):

As has been mentioned:

```
expect(4).to eq(4)
```

This is specifically testing the value that you've sent in as the parameter to the method.  When you're trying to test for raised errors when you do the same thing:

```
expect(raise "fail!").to raise_error
```

Your argument is evaluated *immediately* and that exception will be thrown and your test will blow up right there.

However, when you use a block (and this is basic ruby), the block contents isn't executed immediately - it's execution is determined by the method you're calling (in this case, the `expect` method handles when to execute your block):

```
expect{raise "fail!"}.to raise_error
```

We can look at an example method that might handle this behavior:

```
def expect(val=nil)
  if block_given?
    begin
      yield
    rescue
      puts "Your block raised an error!"
    end
  else
    puts "The value under test is #{val}"
  end
end
```

You can see here that it's the `expect` method that is manually rescuing your error so that it can test whether or not errors are raised, etc.  `yield` is a ruby method's way of executing whatever block was passed to the method.

Answer (score 15):

In the first case, when you pass a block to `expect`, the execution of the block doesn't occur until it's time to evaluate the result, at which point the RSpec code can catch any error that are raised and check it against the expectation.

In the second case, the error is raised when the argument to `expect` is evaluated, so the `expect` code has no chance to get involved.

As for rules, you pass a block or a `Proc` if you're trying to test *behavior* (e.g. raising errors, changing some value). Otherwise, you pass a "conventional" argument, in which case the value of that argument is what is tested.

Comment: So the failure has more to do with me being able to raise an exception and catch errors? So we use blocks specifically in these cases where we want to test errors?

Comment: So what's the rule here? use blocks for testing behaviour and normal expect method call to test...?

Comment: You're using an `expect` method call in each case, but yes, you'd pass a block if you want to test behavior and the non-block approach to test "values".

Comment: Note that I deleted an earlier comment of mine that you'd use a block to test for receiving messages, as an example. I was confused/wrong about that and have updated the answer accordingly.