# When to use curly braces vs parenthesis in expect Rspec method?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I had a test that did this:

```
expect(@parser.parse('adsadasdas')).to raise_error(Errno::ENOENT)
```

and it didn't work.  I changed to:

```
expect { @parser.parse('adsadasdas') }.to raise_error(Errno::ENOENT)
```

And it worked.

When do we use curly braces and when do we use parentheses with expect?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In response to OP's comment, I've edited and completely rewritten my answer.  I realize that my original answer was oversimplified, so much so that it could be considered incorrect.

Your question was actually addressed somewhat by this other [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960831/rspec-expect-vs-expect-with-block-whats-the-difference).

One poster, [Peter Alfvin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19961035/934047), makes a good point when he says:

> As for rules, you pass a block or a Proc if you're trying to test
>   behavior (e.g. raising errors, changing some value). Otherwise, you
>   pass a "conventional" argument, in which case the value of that
>   argument is what is tested.

The reason you're encountering the phenomenon you're seeing has to do with the raising of errors.  When you pass `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')` as an argument (use parentheses) to `expect`, you are essentially telling ruby:

1. Evaluate `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')` first.
2. Take the result and pass this to `expect`.
3. `expect` should see if this result matches my expectation (that is, that `Errno:ENOENT` will be raised).

But, what happens is: when ruby evaluates `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')`, an error is raised right then and there.  Ruby doesn't even get a chance to pass the result on to `expect`.  (For all we care, you could have passed `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')` as an argument to any function... like `multiply()` or `capitalize()`)  The error is raised, and `expect` never even gets a chance to do its work.

But when you pass `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')` as a proc (a code block) to `expect` using curly braces, what you are telling ruby is this:

1. `expect`, get ready to do some work.
2. `expect`, I would like you to keep track of what happens as we evaluate `@parser.parse('adsadasdas')`.
3. Ok, `expect`, did the code block that was just evaluated raise a `Errno:ENOENT` error?  I was expecting that it would.

When you pass a code block to `expect`, you are telling `expect` that you want it to examine the resulting behavior, the changes, made by your code block's execution, and then to let you know if it meets up to the expectations that you provide it.

When you pass an argument to `expect`, you are telling *ruby* to evaluate that argument to come to some value *before* `expect` even gets involved, and then you are passing that value to `expect` to see if it meets up to some expectation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Look at this here though: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations -- It is using expect with parentheses, as a method...Why?

Answer (score 11):

TL;DR: use `expect(exp)` to specify something about the *value* of `exp` and use `expect { exp }` to specify a *side effect* that occurs when `exp` is executed.

---

Let's unpack this a bit. Most of RSpec's matchers are *value* matchers. They match (or not) against any ruby object. In contrast, a handful of RSpec's matchers can only be matched against a block, because they have to observe the block while it's running in order to operate properly. These matchers concern side effects that take place (or not) while the block executes. The matcher would have no way to tell if the named side effect had occurred unless it is passed a block to execute.  Let's consider the built-in block matchers (as of RSpec 3.1) one-by-one:

#### `raise_error`

Consider that one can return an exception from a method, and that is different than raising the exception. Raising an exception is a side effect, and can only be observed by the matcher by it executing the block with an appropriate `rescue` clause. Thus, this matcher must receive a block to work properly.

#### `throw_symbol`

Throwing symbols is similar to raising errors -- it causes a stack jump and is a side effect that can only be observed by running a block inside an appropriate `catch` block.

#### `change`

Mutation to state is a side effect. The matcher can only tell if there was a change to some state by checking the state before hand, running the block, then checking the state after.

#### `output`

I/O is a side effect. For the `output` matcher to work, it has to replace the appropriate stream (`$stdout` or `$stderr`) with a new `StringIO, execute the block, restore the stream to its original value, and then check the contents of the`StringIO`.

#### `yield_control`/`yield_with_args`/`yield_with_no_args`/`yield_with_successive_args`

These matchers are a bit different. Yielding isn't really a side effect (it's really just syntactic sugar for calling another function provided by the caller), but yielding can't be observed by looking at the return value of the expression. For the yield matchers to work, they provide a `probe` object that you pass on to the method-under-test as a block using the `&probe` syntax:

```
expect { |probe| [1, 2, 3].each(&probe) }.to yield_with_successive_args(1, 2, 3)
```

---

What do all these matchers have in common? None of them can work on simple ruby values. Instead, they all have to wrap a block in an appropriate context (i.e. rescuing, catching or checking before/after values).

Note that in RSpec 3, we [added some logic](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/pull/530) to provide users clear errors when they use the wrong `expect` form with a given matcher. However, in the specific case of `expect(do_something).to raise_error`, there's nothing we can do to provide you a clear explanation there -- if `do_something` raises an error (as you expect it to...), then the error is raised before ruby evaluates the `to` argument (the `raise_error` matcher) so RSpec has no way to check with the matcher to see if supports value or block expectations.

Comment: [A side effect refers simply to the modification of some kind of state](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect)

Answer (score 6):

in short:

- use curly-brace (a block): when you want to test the `behavior`
- use parenthesis when you want to test the `returned value`

worth reading: `As for rules, you pass a block or a Proc if you're trying to test behavior (e.g. raising errors, changing some value). Otherwise, you pass a "conventional" argument, in which case the value of that argument is what is tested.` - [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19960831/rspec-expect-vs-expect-with-block-whats-the-difference#answer-19961035)

Comment: Being able to sum things up in a short, concice way is a gift.

Answer (score 1):

In the test written with parentheses, the code is executed normally, including all normal error handling. The curly-brace syntax defines a block object upon which you can place the expectation. It encapsulates the code you expect to be broken and allows rspec to catch the error and provide its own handling (in this case, a successful test).

You can think of it this way as well: with the parentheses, the code is executed before being passed to the `expect` method, but with the block, `expect` will run the code itself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't understand when would I want to use expect with {} or (). ```expect { @parser.parse(url) }.to include(known_url)``` would not work, but if I use it with parentheses, it would work. Why?