# Rspec - Testing uniqueness on a has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, tdd, factory-bot

I'm trying to test that a model can have many values but not duplicate values.

I have the following models: school, tag, school_tag. A school can have many tags, and a tag can belong to many schools. An example tag, 'Art', 'Science', 'Math', etc.

```
class School
  has_many :school_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags, through: :school_tags
end

class Tag
  has_many :school_tags, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :schools, through: :school_tags
end

class SchoolTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :tag, foreign_key: 'tag_id'
  belongs_to :school, foreign_key: 'school_id'

  validates_uniqueness_of :tag_id, scope: :school_id, message: 'has already been assigned to this school'
end
```

My current test is below. It adds some valid tags first, but then tries to add a tag that's already been added to that collection.

```
before(:each) do
  @school = FactoryGirl.create(:school)
  @tag1 = FactoryGirl.create(:tag) #creates "Test1"
  @tag2 = FactoryGirl.create(:tag) #creates "Test2"
end

it 'can have multiple tags but not duplicates' do
    @school.tags << @tag1
    @school.tags << @tag2
    expect(@school.save).to be(true) #works
    expect(@school.tags.count).to eq(2) #works

    #FAILS
    expect(@school.tags << @tag1).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
    expect(@school.tags.count).to eq(2)
end
```

The part where it fails is here:

```
expect(@school.tags << @tag1).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

This is the error I get back:

```
Failure/Error: expect(@school.tags << @tag1).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
     ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
       Validation failed: Schooltype has already been assigned
```

Does it have anything to do with using `<<`? How would I go about testing this?

**ANSWER:** 
Aside from the selected answer below, here is a reference to another question explaining why this happens

[When to use curly braces vs parenthesis in expect Rspec method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567838/when-to-use-curly-braces-vs-parenthesis-in-expect-rspec-method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expect` with raise should be wrapped in a block

```
expect(@school.tags << @tag1).to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```

should be

```
expect{@school.tags << @tag1}.to raise_error(ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
```