# Ruby, rspec Expect error when testing method

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have a method that looks like `build_object(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5)` I want to test this method when a certain value is passed for arg5.

I am trying something like

`expect(my_method(p1, p2, p3, p4, bad5)).to raise_error(ArgumentError)`

I get the following error:

```
ArgumentError:
   The expect syntax does not support operator matchers, so you must pass a matcher to `#to`.
```

I am very new to Ruby and rspec testing, so any help is appreciated. Please explain what your answer is doing so that I learn.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When writing a spec that checks for `raise_error`, you must use the block-syntax `{}` for `expect`:

```
expect { my_method(p1, p2, p3, p4, bad5) }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

There is a much more in-depth explanation in [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567838/3784008), but you asked for an explanation so I'll give you an abbreviated one:

Most rspec matchers are value matchers. That means that something like this:

```
expect(some_method).to eq(value)
```

is really saying:

> perform `some_method` and get its return value, then compare its return value to `value`, and judge the success or failure of this spec on that comparison

When you're trying to test some piece of code that has a side effect, like possibly raising an exception, rspec needs to receive a block of code to run. It's a bit more like:

```
expect { <some block of code> }.to raise_error(ArgumentError)
```

> perform `<some block of code>`, and then compare what happens when that code is executed to what is expected to happen, and judge the success or failure of this spec on that comparison

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26934874/3784008) for the above-linked question goes into detail about when you need to use `expect {}` and when you need to use `expect()`.