# Is there are a difference between change(receiver, message) and change { block }

Tags: ruby, rspec

I found that assertion method `change` used in two different ways

```
expect { createRecord.call }.to change(Record, :count).by(1)
```

vs

```
expect { createRecord.call }.to change { Record.count }.by(1)
```

I tried to dig into source code, and found that passed block will be called if block provided.
Without block message will be "sent" to the receiver.

I was wonder are there some scenarios where one should be preferred over another?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ruby, rspec Expect error when testing method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53053754/ruby-rspec-expect-error-when-testing-method)

Comment: @anothermh, sorry, but no, linked question is about `expect(value)` vs `expect { expression }`, my question is specifically about behavior of `change`, because given expression or values will be evaluated twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not everything maps so neatly to the `send` approach. For example:

```
expect { createRecord.call }.to change { Record.count(OtherRecord.param) }.by(1)
```

Where there's no way to represent that as a simple `send(*args)` as:

```
expect { createRecord.call }.to change(Record, :count, OtherRecord.param).by(1)
```

This evaluates `OtherRecord.param` as the `expect` line executes, not at the right before and after interval.

It's provided for feature-completeness and to give you complete control.

In short the block form *runs the exact block twice* while the other evaluates the arguments once and makes a `send` call twice.

Comment: Thanks, I see cases where one can be preferred than another.