# output matcher expected block but was not a block

Tags: rspec

here is a snippet from my spec:

context "Given array [1,2,3] and block {|e| puts e if e == 1}" do

```
subject { Array.new([1,2,3]) }

it "prints out 1 and returns [1,2,3]" do
  expect(subject.my_each { |e| puts e if e == 1 }).to output("1\n").to_stdout
  expect(subject.my_each { |e| puts e if e == 1 }).to eql([1,2,3])
end
```

end

here is the Rspec output:

1) .my_each Given array [1,2,3] and block {|e| puts e if e == 1} prints out 1 and returns [1,2,3]
     Failure/Error: expect(subject.my_each { |e| puts e if e == 1 }).to output("1\n").to_stdout

```
   expected block to output "1\n" to stdout, but was not a block
   Diff:
   @@ -1,2 +1 @@
   -1

 # ./spec/enumerable_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19960831/7764738), I changed my expect to this:
expect { subject.my_each { |e| puts e if e == 1 } }.to output("1\n").to_stdout