# RSpec example fails with the error I'm expecting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, rspec

Using RSpec with Rails 6.0.0
I'm specifying that a record needs to be deleted after an acion is performed. To do this I call `reload` on the object and expect it to raise an`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error

Ironically the test fails because of an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error. What's with that?

Here's the relevant part of my spec:

```
  context 'when deleting a notice' do
    let(:notice) { FactoryBot.create(:program_notice) }
    let(:request_proto) { Sil::Rev79::Id.new(uuid: notice.id) }
    subject { run_rpc(:DeleteNotice, request_proto) }

    context 'as admin user' do
      include_context 'admin user'

      it "deletes the notice" do
        expect(subject).to be_a Google::Protobuf::Empty
        expect(notice.reload).to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
      end

    end
  end
```

and this is the failure message:

> 3) ProgramsController when deleting a notice as admin user deletes
>   the notice
>        Failure/Error: expect(notice.reload).to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
>
> ```
>  ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
>    Couldn't find ProgramNotice with 'id'=47e2d9c1-a009-4b9c-a7a5-2279ae74d74d
>  # ./spec/rpc/programs_controller_spec.rb:360:in `block (4 levels) in <main>'
> ```

line 360 in the test file is that second `expect` statement.

Comment: Try `expect { notice.reload }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`. Read the [doc](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs/built-in-matchers/raise-error-matcher) here. Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19962317/2767755) to know why block is important in this case.

Answer (score 4):

The second expectation needs to set up with a block, not as a parameter:

`expect { notice.reload }.to raise_error ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`